# WSO2 - Identity Server - Adding multiple event handler

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have followed some tutorials related to creating custom event handlers for WSO2 identity server version 6.1.0 (latest). My question is can we add multiple event handlers at the same time?
For example i created an event handler for the password reset on first login, then i want to use a custom event handler for otp, in both cases, i should define the event handler under deployment.toml: under this tag [[event_handler]].
In case i have two handlers, what is the correct way to configure both under deployment.toml? is it the following:

```
# for count login for password reset on first login

[[event_handler]]
name="customUserLogin"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

# for otp called from external apis 

[[event_handler]]
name= "smsOtp"
properties.enabled=true
properties.tokenLength=6
properties.triggerNotification=true
properties.alphanumericToken=true
# OTP validation failure reason will be sent in the response.
properties.showValidationFailureReason=false
properties.tokenValidityPeriod=120
# Same valid OTP will be resent, if issued within the interval.
# Set '0' to always send a new OTP.
# Should be less than the 'tokenValidityPeriod' value.
properties.tokenRenewalInterval=60
# Throttle OTP generation requests from the same user Id.
# Set '0' for no throttling.
properties.resendThrottleInterval=30
# Set the maximum validation attempts allowed until the generated sms-otp expires.
properties.maxValidationAttemptsAllowed=5
```

or the following:

```
# for count login for password reset on first login

[[event_handler]]
name="customUserLogin"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]
# for otp called from external apis 
name= "smsOtp"
properties.enabled=true
```

but in this case the name tag will be defined twice...

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The custom event configurations can be added as follows to {wso2is-home}/repository/conf/deployment.toml file.

```
[[event_handler]]
name= "customEventOne"
subscriptions =["PRE_SET_EVENT","POST_SET_EVENT"]

[[event_handler]]
name= "customEventTwo"
subscriptions =["PRE_SET_EVENT","POST_SET_EVENT"]
```

The events which need to subscribe to the handler can be listed in subscriptions.